# MySQL backup file getting classified as spam

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, mysql, spam-prevention, false-positive

Guys in my java application there is an option backup and mail..here  sql db get backup with mysqldump..when it does a backup file created..then i mail it through java..for that I used JFileChooser and browse the backup file and mail it..
But my problem is when I send the mail it goes to spam folder not to inbox..we think my file name is backup.sql..I think the file format is not familiar that's why it goes to spam..Is there any solution for that something like zip and send..But I want that solution through java.

Comment: So... some anti-spam software somewhere is classifying it as spam. How are we supposed to solve that without more information? Are you talking about GMail, SpamAssassin, greylisting... what kind of anti-spam technology is being used? Is it under the control of you or your customers?

Comment: 1: How and what do you use to send emails? 2: Depending on mail service they might classify .sql files as spam, as they probably would classify .exe files as spam as well. 3: Yes you could zip and send, and Java is capable of creating zip files.

Comment: I just use a code in this site itself to compose and send emails through java..how to use zip software with java..I want like this

Comment: when I clicked backup button in my application show where it should save.then there is a button to mail it to a given email address..I can manage up to that..but mail goes to spam folder so i want it to zip and send..But not with windows it also do with my java application

Comment: You can do that by using `ZipOutputStream` along with `ZipEntry`'s